# I need more detail using @font-face in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to use @font-face, and this is what my code looks like:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: myFont;
    src: url(AccidentalPresidency.ttf);
};

div {
    font-family: myFont;
};
```

The font is not changing to the font I found at http://www.1001freefonts.com/accidental_presidency.font

I found the link "AccidentalPresidency.ttf" on the webpage for the font.

I am using Codecademy in the newest version of Chrome. I have never used @font-face before.

Answer (score 0):

have you applied the font-family for all elements?

try:

```
* {font-family: myFont}
```

Comment: You could add an !important on the end just to make sure.  But remove it after your test.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the font and save it on your project folder. For example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Font';
    src: url('../css/AccidentalPresidency.ttf');
}

div {
    font-family: 'My Font';
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the `''` on the source and font name. Remove the semicolon at the end of `}`.